# Wi-Fi Connectivity Issues - Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: networking, network-manager

since my upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04, I have been unable to connect to my home wi-fi network despite using the same WPA2 credentials. I can still however, connect to my wireless hotspot. I have journalctl output as shown below:

```
May 02 17:32:28 mylinuxbox systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
May 02 17:32:28 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537948.3632] NetworkManager (version 1.36.4) is starting... (for the first time)
May 02 17:32:28 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537948.3633] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 10-globally-managed-devices.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (etc: default-wifi-powersave-on.conf)
May 02 17:32:28 mylinuxbox systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
May 02 17:32:28 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537948.3672] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
May 02 17:32:28 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537948.3998] manager[0x563fcc492000]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
May 02 17:32:28 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537948.3998] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
May 02 17:32:28 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537948.8789] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
May 02 17:32:28 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537948.8790] hostname: static hostname changed from (none) to "mylinuxbox"
May 02 17:32:28 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537948.8798] dns-mgr[0x563fcc46b2a0]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=unmanaged (auto), plugin=systemd-resolved
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.0102] rfkill0: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill0) (driver iwlwifi)
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.0113] manager[0x563fcc492000]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.0113] manager[0x563fcc492000]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.0141] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.4/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.0160] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.4/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.0166] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.4/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.0177] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.4/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.0188] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.4/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.0197] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.0198] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.0198] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.0213] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.4/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so")
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.0213] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.0213] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.0215] ifupdown:       interface-parser: parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.0216] ifupdown:       interface-parser: finished parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.0297] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.0297] device (lo): carrier: link connected
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.0300] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.0311] manager: (enxf8e43b920faf): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.0316] device (wlp0s20f3): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.0320] manager: (wlp0s20f3): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.0322] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.2265] manager: (virbr1): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.2275] failed to open /run/network/ifstate
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.2411] modem-manager: ModemManager available
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.2423] manager: (74:9E:F5:B1:2A:E6): new Bluetooth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5)
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.3132] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.3134] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlp0s20f3 created
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.3136] manager: (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/6)
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.3139] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:32:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537949.6526] manager: (virbr0): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/7)
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.0045] agent-manager: agent[e58e246269bdd40c,:1.62/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/121]: agent registered
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.3772] policy: auto-activating connection 'My_cruddy_network' (33008dab-dd15-44ca-9fc1-308c2fccf021)
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.3776] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: starting connection 'My_cruddy_network' (33008dab-dd15-44ca-9fc1-308c2fccf021)
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.3777] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.3779] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.3780] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.3782] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) access point 'My_cruddy_network' has security, but secrets are required.
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.3782] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.3783] sup-iface[f288b1703a592371,0,wlp0s20f3]: wps: type pbc start...
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.3788] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.3789] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.3790] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) connection 'My_cruddy_network' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.3790] Config: added 'ssid' value 'My_cruddy_network'
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.3790] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.3790] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:************'
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.3791] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.3791] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.3791] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.4075] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.4075] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.4343] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.4343] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.4501] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.4502] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.4973] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
May 02 17:32:32 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537952.4973] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
May 02 17:32:40 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537960.8333] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> disconnected
May 02 17:32:40 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537960.8334] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) disconnected during association, asking for new key
May 02 17:32:40 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537960.8335] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'supplicant-disconnect', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:32:40 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537960.8338] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> disconnected
May 02 17:32:40 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537960.9334] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 02 17:32:40 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537960.9334] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 02 17:32:41 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537961.0440] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
May 02 17:32:41 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537961.0440] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> inactive
May 02 17:32:52 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651537972.7871] agent-manager: agent[a55fc8f71cc5b222,:1.97/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1001]: agent registered
May 02 17:33:28 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538008.5899] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:33:28 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538008.5904] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:33:28 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538008.5907] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) connection 'My_cruddy_network' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
May 02 17:33:28 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538008.5907] Config: added 'ssid' value 'My_cruddy_network'
May 02 17:33:28 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538008.5907] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
May 02 17:33:28 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538008.5908] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:************'
May 02 17:33:28 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538008.5908] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
May 02 17:33:28 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538008.5908] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
May 02 17:33:28 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538008.5908] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
May 02 17:33:28 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538008.6142] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
May 02 17:33:28 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538008.6142] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> scanning
May 02 17:33:28 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538008.8004] manager: (docker0): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/8)
May 02 17:33:30 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538010.3380] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
May 02 17:33:30 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538010.3380] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
May 02 17:33:30 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538010.3640] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 02 17:33:30 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538010.3640] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 02 17:33:30 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538010.3835] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
May 02 17:33:30 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538010.3835] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
May 02 17:33:30 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538010.4579] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
May 02 17:33:30 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538010.4579] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
May 02 17:33:38 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538018.7872] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> disconnected
May 02 17:33:38 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538018.7873] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) disconnected during association, asking for new key
May 02 17:33:38 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538018.7874] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'supplicant-disconnect', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:33:38 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538018.7877] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> disconnected
May 02 17:33:38 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538018.8876] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
May 02 17:33:38 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538018.8877] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> inactive
May 02 17:34:25 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538065.0839] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: need-auth -> deactivating (reason 'connection-removed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:34:25 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538065.0842] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTING
May 02 17:34:25 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538065.0852] manager: startup complete
May 02 17:34:25 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538065.0857] audit: op="connection-delete" uuid="33008dab-dd15-44ca-9fc1-308c2fccf021" name="My_cruddy_network" pid=6055 uid=1001 result="success"
May 02 17:34:25 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <warn>  [1651538065.1311] device (wlp0s20f3): Deactivation failed: GDBus.Error:fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.NotConnected: This interface is not connected
May 02 17:34:25 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538065.1312] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'connection-removed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:34:25 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538065.1323] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
May 02 17:35:16 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538116.8189] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: starting connection 'My_cruddy_network' (5ed72c4b-017e-427b-80c3-53a8e56a2740)
May 02 17:35:16 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538116.8191] audit: op="connection-add-activate" uuid="5ed72c4b-017e-427b-80c3-53a8e56a2740" name="My_cruddy_network" pid=6457 uid=0 result="success"
May 02 17:35:16 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538116.8196] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:35:16 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538116.8200] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
May 02 17:35:16 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538116.8204] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:35:16 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538116.8207] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) access point 'My_cruddy_network' has security, but secrets are required.
May 02 17:35:16 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538116.8207] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:35:16 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538116.8209] sup-iface[f288b1703a592371,0,wlp0s20f3]: wps: type pbc start...
May 02 17:35:16 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <warn>  [1651538116.8319] device (wlp0s20f3): no secrets: No agents were available for this request.
May 02 17:35:16 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538116.8319] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:35:16 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538116.8324] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
May 02 17:35:16 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <warn>  [1651538116.8328] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: failed for connection 'My_cruddy_network'
May 02 17:35:16 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538116.8331] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:35:16 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538116.8480] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
May 02 17:35:16 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538116.8481] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> scanning
May 02 17:35:16 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538116.8796] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
May 02 17:35:16 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538116.8796] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> inactive
May 02 17:35:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538129.4999] audit: op="connection-update" uuid="5ed72c4b-017e-427b-80c3-53a8e56a2740" name="My_cruddy_network" pid=6467 uid=1001 result="success"
May 02 17:35:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538129.5059] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: starting connection 'My_cruddy_network' (5ed72c4b-017e-427b-80c3-53a8e56a2740)
May 02 17:35:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538129.5060] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="5ed72c4b-017e-427b-80c3-53a8e56a2740" name="My_cruddy_network" pid=6467 uid=1001 result="success"
May 02 17:35:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538129.5062] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:35:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538129.5066] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
May 02 17:35:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538129.5070] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:35:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538129.5074] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) access point 'My_cruddy_network' has security, but secrets are required.
May 02 17:35:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538129.5075] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:35:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538129.5077] sup-iface[f288b1703a592371,0,wlp0s20f3]: wps: type pbc start...
May 02 17:35:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538129.5253] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
May 02 17:35:29 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538129.5254] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> scanning
May 02 17:35:39 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <warn>  [1651538139.9189] device (wlp0s20f3): no secrets: User canceled the secrets request.
May 02 17:35:39 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538139.9190] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:35:39 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538139.9196] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
May 02 17:35:39 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <warn>  [1651538139.9201] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: failed for connection 'My_cruddy_network'
May 02 17:35:39 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538139.9205] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:36:37 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538197.7471] audit: op="connection-update" uuid="5ed72c4b-017e-427b-80c3-53a8e56a2740" name="My_cruddy_network" pid=6653 uid=1001 result="success"
May 02 17:36:37 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538197.7546] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: starting connection 'My_cruddy_network' (5ed72c4b-017e-427b-80c3-53a8e56a2740)
May 02 17:36:37 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538197.7547] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="5ed72c4b-017e-427b-80c3-53a8e56a2740" name="My_cruddy_network" pid=6653 uid=1001 result="success"
May 02 17:36:37 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538197.7548] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:36:37 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538197.7552] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
May 02 17:36:37 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538197.7556] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:36:37 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538197.7560] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) access point 'My_cruddy_network' has security, but secrets are required.
May 02 17:36:37 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538197.7560] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:36:37 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538197.7563] sup-iface[f288b1703a592371,0,wlp0s20f3]: wps: type pbc start...
May 02 17:36:41 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538201.7008] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:36:41 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538201.7014] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:36:41 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538201.7019] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) connection 'My_cruddy_network' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
May 02 17:36:41 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538201.7020] Config: added 'ssid' value 'My_cruddy_network'
May 02 17:36:41 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538201.7020] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
May 02 17:36:41 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538201.7021] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:************'
May 02 17:36:41 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538201.7021] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
May 02 17:36:41 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538201.7021] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
May 02 17:36:41 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538201.7021] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
May 02 17:36:41 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538201.7307] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
May 02 17:36:41 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538201.7308] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
May 02 17:36:41 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538201.7603] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 02 17:36:41 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538201.7604] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 02 17:36:41 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538201.7789] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
May 02 17:36:41 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538201.7790] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
May 02 17:36:41 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538201.8512] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
May 02 17:36:41 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538201.8512] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
May 02 17:36:50 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538210.2022] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> disconnected
May 02 17:36:50 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538210.2023] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) disconnected during association, asking for new key
May 02 17:36:50 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538210.2024] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'supplicant-disconnect', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:36:50 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538210.2030] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> disconnected
May 02 17:36:50 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538210.3022] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
May 02 17:36:50 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538210.3023] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> inactive
May 02 17:38:50 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <warn>  [1651538330.2119] device (wlp0s20f3): no secrets: No agents were available for this request.
May 02 17:38:50 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538330.2119] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 02 17:38:50 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538330.2123] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
May 02 17:38:50 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <warn>  [1651538330.2127] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: failed for connection 'My_cruddy_network'
May 02 17:38:50 mylinuxbox NetworkManager[2040]: <info>  [1651538330.2131] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

The SSID in question is "My_cruddy_network". It seems to want to connect with the correct key if I look at the 'key-mgmy' value because it is a wpa2 network with AES. I don't know why it goes from disconnected -> authenticating. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try removing your wifi settings in Network Manager and readding the network - does that help?

Comment: @ThomasWard that does not work sadly.

Comment: Any updates pertaining to this, sadly this is my daily computer and not having WiFi work is a huge inconvenience.